# How can I clear memcached WordPress site options by hand?

Tags: options, site-url

Ater rebooting a memcache node, I am getting an error on root blog only, with a telling error log message from wp-includes/ms-settings.php.

```
[Thu Jul 07 18:55:27 2011] [error] [client 12.34.56.78] PHP Warning:  Attempt to assign property of non-object in /var/www/domain.php/wp-includes/ms-settings.php on line 114
```

Dumping the $current_blog var from that file shows there's no site data loaded into the object, just a couple plugin references, which is why lines like these are failing:

```
    $blog_id = $current_blog->blog_id;
    $public  = $current_blog->public;
```

How can I clear site options in memcache by hand? What are the keys?

Answer (score 1):

The variable in my copy of wordpress on the line your error indicates is actually $current_site as opposed to $current_blog (I may have a newer version of WP).  I believe you can clear that by changing the value of the option_name "siteurl" or "blogname" in your wp_options table on your database.

Comment: $current_site was probably a slip (mid-outage, I was going nuts). It turns out that it was not the database -- just the cached version in memcache -- so this wouldn't have helped. I actually just needed to delete memcache key by hand. Thank you for the answer, but I'd still like to see the key/value pair under which this is stored.